# Commit early and often AND easily see files/lines worked on for a feature

Tags: git, version-control

I know it's best practice to commit early and often. When I'm working on a feature I always find myself doing the opposite so that files and lines that have changed are highlighted and I can easily come back to them.

How can I commit early and often but still retain the ability to quickly see code that has been added/changed, which may require further work to implement a feature?

If there was a way to perhaps highlight files and lines that have commits in my branch and not in master (or another arbitrary branch) then that would be an ideal solution.

Comment: so something like `git diff @{u}...@` is not good enough? (notice it's `...`, not `..`).

Comment: I have integrated `git jump` into my workflow. https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/git-jump